# border-radius doesn't affect the background of an inner div (Chrome, Opera)

Tags: css

Is it possible to use border-radius on a div (in Chrome and Opera) so that the inner div background would also be affected? **If not, how else can this effect be achieved?**

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fE58b/1/

It works well in IE9 & FF7.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried applying the border-radius to the inner div as well?

Comment: Of course, but it would work only if the sizes were the same, but that's not this case.

Comment: I know you didn't ask about Safari, which is also Webkit like Chrome,  but I'm noticing that `border-radius` starts working when you convert `20%` into pixels.

Comment: @Sparky672: I've just installed Safari to try it out, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: It's not a complete solution.  When it's set to `20%` I see square corners on everything.  When it's set to `20px` I see rounded corners on the `div` but the image is still not cropped.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you just move the background image from `#content` to `.box`:

```
.box {
     background:url(...so_70s_background.jpg) top left repeat;
}
```

Also if you really need to have the borders in a separate div, you can always add new divs outside the box:

```
<div class="box-outer">
    <div class="box">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Just make sure to apply:

```
.box-outer {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Makes no difference in Safari.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that the background has to be in a separate div. Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: You mean in a separate div from the borders? Also why?

Comment: @Sparky672: He didn't mention Safari support was required.

Comment: @jsalonen: Yes, exactly. Because I'm using a jquery plugin to generate the background. It has to be in an inner div for the plugin to work.

Comment: @Drejon: Do you really need to put the borders into exactly that div? I don't see a reason why you still couldn't like add something like `<div class="box-outer"></div>` as a placeholder for the plugin and append the borders inside this element.

Comment: @jsalonen: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Weirdly, this answer is working fine in Safari when `20%` is changed to `20px`.  See http://jsfiddle.net/fE58b/14/

Comment: What is your OS and browser versions? It works both with `20%` and `20px` on all of my browsers (Safari 5.1.4, Opera 12.00, Chrome 19.0.1084.56 m; Windows 7).

Comment: @jsalonen: I've tried it, but it's not working - the plugin affects the wrong div. And even if it would work, the issue still remains (the content is not affected): http://jsfiddle.net/fE58b/15/

Comment: Does it break even if you rename `.box-outer` to `.box` and `.box` to `.box-inner`?

Comment: The `%` versus `px` thing is clearly a browser issue as a change in units should make no difference.  Safari 4.1.3.  And to the OP, if the code is working in a jsFiddle, then it should also work for you if you've applied it correctly.

Comment: @jsalonen: Yep, it does. It won't make a difference, because the background is in the same div as the border-radius. The plugin also rotates the div, in which the background is located - I need to avoid that.

Comment: Oh right, got that. However, as has been demonstrated, browsers don't support use of `border-radius` along with `overflow: hidden` in the same `div` very well.

Comment: So there probably isn't even an alternate solution for this kind of problem, is there?

Answer (score 0):

So, as Cristi stated above, some browsers seem to have a little trouble with clipping overflowing children along the curved border of their parents. It appears that, in order (for at least Webkit) to render child overflow affected by parent border-radius, both parent and child must be **statically positioned**.

Furthermore, even with this static positioning, it appears that setting an opacity value for the child element will cause it to break the overflow boundaries of its parent (if I had to guess, I'd imagine this has something to do with the opacity value triggering hardware accelerated graphics, in which case a 3D-transform will produce the same glitch).

Luckily, you can use an absolutely-positioned grandparent control the dimensions and position of its static children, and `rgba` on background and text to simulate element opacity. I just so happen to have a [jsfiddle snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/GjvEE/) demonstrating some of these workarounds which you might find helpful.

Comment: I've set the opacity only to demonstrate the border-radius overflow. What do you mean with 'statically positioned'?

Comment: Never used that one before, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I've created an updated of your JSFiddle that has been tested in Chrome, Safari and Opera, and works in the first two. http://jsfiddle.net/fE58b/16/ (notice the removal of the opacity attribute in favor of a semi-transparent background image). I'm honestly not sure what the deal is with Opera. As far as I can tell, the only way to make Presto render the elements as expected is to apply a border-radius to the inner div as well as its container.

Answer (score 0):

user following to solve border radous issue

```
         border-radius: 20%;        /* FOR ALL NEW BROWSER OF HIGHER VERSION*/
    -webkit-border-radius: 20%;      *FOR ALL OHTER OLD BROWSER*/
    -moz-border-radius: 20%;     /* FOR MOZILLA FF*/
```